# Law of Demeter original definition

Tags: oop, law-of-demeter

I've been trying to understand Law of Demeter but there is so much conflicting information and opinions on it, that i decided to read the original research paper (1988) (https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/papers/law-of-demeter/oopsla88-law-of-demeter.pdf) - but i'm very confused by one of the rules in it.

The rules are as follows:

> For all classes C, and for all methods M attached to C, all objects to which M sends a
> message must be
>
> 1. M’s argument objects, including the self
>    object or
> 2. The instance variable objects of C.
>
> (Objects created by M, or by functions or
> methods which M calls, and objects in global
> variables are considered as arguments of M.)

And this all makes sense to me. Except for one part (paraphrasing to simplify):

**Objects CREATED by methods which M calls are considered as arguments of M** (adheres to 1st rule)

The paper also says this:

> The Law prohibits the nesting of generic
> accessor function calls, which return objects that are
> not instance variable objects.
>
> It allows the nesting of constructor function calls.
>
> An accessor function is
> a function which returns an object which did exist
> before the function is called. A constructor function
> returns an object which did not exist before the function is called.

so then, the example below is considered adhering to LoD, if each method returns a new instance of some kind of object ?

```
function text(BookClass book) {
    book.pages().last().text()
}
```

but doesn't adhere to the law if those same methods return existing instances of objects / primitive values ?
it doesn't matter what kind of object is returned, just as long as it's created in the called method ? so then where is the loose coupling, information hiding and the other benefits, if this adheres to the law of Demeter ?

I feel like i'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

The Law of Demeter is written to be language-agnostic, which accounts for the generic definitions of "accessor" and "constructor".

A given (OO) language typically has specific syntax for creating new Objects. For example, in Java, a "constructor function" is always preceded by the `new` keyword. So the generic description,

> Objects created by M, or by functions or methods which M calls,

...allows M to make constructor calls using the `new` keyword in Java. Objects returned from these constructor calls, "are considered as arguments of M."

Here is the Law of Demeter in Java code, following the order in which the rules are described in the aforementioned paper.

```java
class Class_C {
    TypeOne instanceVariable;

    void method_M(TypeThree argument) {
        // Allowed to call methods on argument variable types.
        // "1. The argument classes of M..."
        TypeFour typeFour = argument.getTypeFour();

        // Allowed to call methods on own (or inherited) types.
        // "1. The argument classes of M (including C)."
        allowed();

        // Allowed to call methods on own (or inherited) instance variable types.
        // "2. The instance variable classes of C."
        TypeTwo typeTwo = instanceVariable.getTypeTwo();

        // Allowed to create Objects and/or call constructor methods.
        // "Objects created by M or by functions or methods which M calls...
        //   are considered as arguments of M."
        String newString = "Hello, Law of Demeter!";
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Allowed to call methods on global variables,
        //   e.g. println() on the 'out' variable of System.
        // "Global variables are considered as arguments of M."
        System.out.println(newString);

        // NOT allowed to call methods on other classes' instance variable types.
        // "The Law _prohibits_ the nesting of generic accessor function calls..."
        //   One accessor call was made to retrieve each of these variable types,
        //     so a second call would be inappropriate nesting.
        typeTwo.notAllowed();
        typeFour.notAllowed();

        // Allowed to call methods on newly-constructed objects.
        // Remember, these "are considered as arguments of M."
        // "[The Law] _allows_ the nesting of constructor function calls."
        //   One constructor call followed by a second call is appropriate nesting.
        newList.add(newString);

        // Note: nested method calls on the _same_ variable type are allowed,
        //   because this does not change the implications of rules 1 and 2.
        argument.aMethodReturningTypeThree().anotherMethodReturningTypeThree();
        instanceVariable.aMethodReturningTypeOne().anotherMethodReturningTypeOne();
    }

    void allowed() {}
}
```

It would be easier to read the LoD if it was written separately for each language using only syntax specific to that language. But to describe a general principle the authors combined terminology. The term "constructor" means different things in different languages. To apply the principle to *your* language, you must substitute the syntax defined by your language. A commonality across languages is that a constructor "returns an object which did not exist before..." In addition, a constructor is defined by the syntax of your language. A method may call this syntax and nest/chain calls onto the new Object.

For example, my language is Java. In Java, the only syntax for a constructor looks like: `new Object()`. This function call does two things.

- It satisfies the common description from the LoD by returning an object which did not exist before.
- It satisfies the definition of a constructor, *in my language*.

Now, having a new object isn't very useful to *my* method unless I call methods on that new object. So the LoD specifically "allows the nesting of constructor function calls" meaning I can chain something like: `new Object().toString()` which would not be allowed if `new Object()` was a normal, non-constructor function.

The phrase, "allows the nesting of constructor function calls" means any number of methods can be called on the new object returned from a constructor. Since these additional methods are *not* constructor function calls themselves, nesting calls onto them is not allowed. In other words, the following can all be called by M.

- `new Object().secondObject()`
- `new Object().thirdObject()`
- `new Object().fourthObject()`

But M cannot call `new Object().secondObject().thirdObject()` because `secondObject()` is not a constructor function call (in my language) and therefore does not allow nesting/chaining. The LoD allows nesting on **constructor** function calls. It does not allow nesting on **all** function calls.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort in helping me.
But my question still remains:
"Objects CREATED by methods which M calls are considered as arguments of M"

`created by methods which M calls`. I'm not talking about a new object being created in the originating method - i'm talking about the objects returned by called methods.

This part below is important distinction:
An accessor function is a function which returns an object which **did exist** before the function is called. A constructor function returns an object which **did not exist** before the function is called.

Comment: I understand. The language-agnostic terminology is confusing, because languages construct objects in different ways. A given language's "constructor function" has specific syntax. In Java, it's a function call preceded by the `new` keyword, which is guaranteed by the language to return a new object. Again, there is syntax _guaranteed by the language_ to create objects. A method is allowed to _directly_ call one of these guaranteed syntaxes. The phrase, "created by M or by functions or methods" is inclusive of syntax across languages, not to say every language guarantees these as constructors.

Comment: Ok, so if "A method is allowed to directly call one of these guaranteed syntaxes", then my other question was - why ?
in my example `book.pages().last().text()` if `pages()` returns a `new Pages` object and `last()` returns a `new Page` object and so on. Then by the definition of this law i can use this method chain.
But then this situation does not grant any of the benefits listed in the research paper (looser coupling, information hiding, narrow interface, information localisation etc.). Why ? what's the point of the law then ?

Comment: In the example `book.pages().last().text()` there are no _direct_ constructor calls.

Comment: Where does it say that there have to be DIRECT constructor calls ?
1. `A constructor function returns an object which did not exist before the function is called.` 2. `It allows the nesting of constructor function calls.` 3. **Objects CREATED by methods which M calls are considered as arguments of M**

Comment: Comment got too long, so I updated the original answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but what's stopping you from doing this then ?
`new Object().getAnotherNewObject()->andAnotherNewObject()->toString()`.

the `getAnotherNewObject()` would return `new AnotherObject()`.

It doesn't say i can only nest once, for the first new object only.

Comment: Updated the original answer again.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, it's definitely a possible interpretation, since the law is a bit ambiguous, but i'm still on the fence:
1. **Objects created by methods which M calls are considered as arguments of M**. `book->getPages()` returns an **Object created by method which M calls**).
2. `constructor function` call does not just have to be `new Object()`. If i call `book->getPages()` and it has `return new Pages()` - by the paper's definition it is also a constructor function (because Pages object did not exist before the call).

Comment: Also the part in the paper that says "The Law prohibits the nesting of generic accessor function calls..." is not the law itself. It's a supposed conclusion that should stem from the law, but i understand the law itself differently, which doesn't come to the same conclusions (clearly).
Maybe the authors gave this law too ambiguous description which led me to this interpretation, probably they meant what you mean, i'm just not certain, because of such conflicting information.