# in terms of oop, what is better way to share state between classes which are has-a related?

Tags: python, object, oop

Sorry if my English is bad, I speak Korean as mother tongue.

Let's suppose class `A` has field of class `B` and `C`, and class `C` has field of class `D`
instance of `B`, `C` is created when instance of `A` is created, being its field.
`D` is similar, too.
now `D` has method, that is dependent to the state of the instance of `B`.
And to accomplish this, I passed the whole instance of `A` for initializing `C`.
sample written in python roughly simplifying unneeded detail:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self, a, num):
        self.a = a
        self.num = num
    def print(self):
        print(self.a.b.cur() * self.num)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.d = D(a, 3)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def cur(self):
        return self.x, self.y

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C(self)
        self.b = B(3, 4)
```

but I felt to pass the self is somewhat weird.
I searched several article for way to sharing state, and they said to make class containing state(or context). but then, how can I track those state properly on each classes?
If I make instance of State like this:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, b=None):
        self.b = b

class D(object):
    def __init__(self, a, num):
        self.a = a
        self.num = num
    def print(self):
        print(self.a.b.cur() * self.num)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.d = D(a, 3)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def cur(self):
        return self.x, self.y

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = C(self)
        self.b = B(3, 4)
        self.state = State(self.b)
```

then to make `D` have access to `self.state` of instance of `A`, it still need to be passed `self`. it seems to be worse than before.

will there be better way? (and I wonder what if being is-a related or not being related.)

Answer (score 0):

If your `D` needs access to a `B`, then that is what it should be given:

```py
class D(object):
    def __init__(self, b, num):
        self.b = b
        self.num = num
    def print(self):
        print(self.b.cur() * self.num)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.d = D(b, 3)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def cur(self):
        return self.x, self.y

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(3, 4)
        self.c = C(self.b)
```

Comment: Also see answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77269165/law-of-demeter-original-definition) about [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: I think fundamentally it is essentially almost same method that passing `self` or passing `self.b`, and I passed `self` instead of `self.b` intentionally. Is it best way to achieve goal?

Comment: It seems Law of Demeter helps me to get something.

Comment: Yes, functionally the two ways are the same. A unit test would not be able to distinguish between them. However, design-wise, it is a small but significant improvement: Now `D` does not have to know about that part of the structure of `A`, allowing it to be more reusable.

Comment: then if `D` need another such as instance of `E` which is field of `A`, is it better to pass a tuple `(self.b, self.e)` instead of `self`?

Comment: In your case, because `A` already has other members, separate variables are better. If, however, your `D` needs all the parts of `A`, then just `self` would then be appropriate.

Comment: that means I should choose `self.c = C(self.b, self.e)` or `self.c = C(self)` instead of `self.c = C((self.b, self.e))`? Did I get correctly?

Comment: Yes, the first one. (The last one doesn't make much sense)